# Skip Lead Assignment Rule for Named Accounts

Tags: trigger, leads, assignment-rules

How can I get leads from specific companies, i.e., leads meeting specific filter criteria,  to skip assignment rules and go directly to a designated rep?

Currently my trigger assigns named account leads based on the email domain of the incoming lead and the named account.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
trigger NamedAccountOwner on Lead (after insert, after update) {
public list<Lead> LeadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>();


Map<string,Id> DomainAccountMap = new Map<string,Id>();
for (Account a :[SELECT ownerID, email_domain__c FROM Account WHERE email_domain__c != null and Named_Account__c = true])
{DomainAccountMap.put(a.email_domain__c, a.ownerId);}

for(integer i=0; i < trigger.new.size();i++){
If(trigger.isinsert || (trigger.isupdate && trigger.new[i].temp__c == 6789 && trigger.old[i].temp__c != 6789)){

ID owner = DomainAccountMap.get(trigger.new[i].email_domain__c);
If(owner != null){

LeadsToUpdate.add(new Lead(Id=trigger.new[i].Id, Ownerid = owner));

}else{}    
}else{}}

If(leadstoupdate.size() > 0){update LeadsToUpdate;}else{}
}
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a question?

Comment: Are you trying to override the Setup | Lead |Assignment rules using this `after insert/update trigger`?  If yes,  Lead Assignment rules will always run after the Lead 'after trigger' and to change the default assignments will require using an @future method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dml option to skip assignment rules.

```
Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= false;
```

Comment: Yeah, but you cannot set that option from within the operation being performed.

Comment: Lead ids to @future method. There, you would: 1) Clone, 2)Delete, 3) Re-insert with operation set.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a checkbox to mark the leads that were assigned by the trigger, and set as criteria in the assignment rule that - checkbox=false.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really old, but still doesn't have an accepted answer, so I'll throw out a solution. I see two possible approaches here:

1. You create some custom checkbox (example below has a checkbox called `Assigned_by_Trigger__c`) or hijack some other field that indicates that the Lead was assigned via your trigger and have a rule in your Lead Assignment rules that if it was assigned via a trigger, keep the owner the same. Make this the first condition.
2. You let Lead Assignment Rules run and then delegate this to an asynchronous method, either `@future` or `Queueable`

Personally, I'd go for option 1, so that it's never in the hands of the "wrong" owner. Additionally, you'll want to take the logic out of your trigger and delegate it to an Apex class (read up on trigger frameworks). There's also no reason for this to process in the `after` context, so I'd move this to `before insert` and `before update`. Lastly, you'll want to either make sure the User triggering this code has permission to update records with inactive owners and/or check to see that the Named Account owner is active.

Your code might look something like this:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, after insert, before update, after update, before delete, after delete) {

    LeadHandler.handleEvents(trigger.isBefore, trigger.isAfter, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate, trigger.isDelete, trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
    
}
```

And the handler class:

```
public class LeadHandler {

    public static void handleEvents(Boolean isBefore, Boolean isAfter, Boolean isInsert, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isDelete, List<Lead> newList, List<Lead> oldList, Map<Id,Lead> newMap, Map<Id,Lead> oldMap){
        try{
            if(isBefore && isInsert){
                assignToNamedAccountOwner(newList);
            }
            if(isAfter && isInsert){
                //do afterInsert
            }
            if(isBefore && isUpdate){
                assignToNamedAccountOwner(newList);
            }
            if(isAfter && isUpdate){
                //do afterUpdate
            }
            if(isBefore && isDelete){
                //do beforeDelete
            }
            if(isAfter && isDelete){
                //do afterDelete
            }            
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            if(newList.size()>0){
                newList[0].addError(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void assignToNamedAccountOwner(List<Lead> newLeads){
        Set<String> leadDomains = new Set<String>();
        for(Lead l : newLeads){
            if(l.email_domain__c != null){
                leadDomains.add(l.email_domain__c);
            }
        }
        Map<String,Account> domainAccMap = new Map<String,Account>();
        for(Account a : [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Owner.isActive, email_domain__c 
                        FROM Account 
                        WHERE email_domain__c = :leadDomains 
                        AND Named_Account__c = TRUE]){
                            domainAccMap.put(a.email_domain__c,a);
        }
        for(Lead l : newLeads){
            if(l.email_domain__c != null){
                Account a = domainAccMap.get(l.email_domain__c);
                if(a != null && a.Owner.isActive){
                    l.OwnerId = a.OwnerId;
                    l.Assigned_by_Trigger__c = TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```